# Encoded Video's path gets changed in database after encoding with ffmpeg and celery and works as normal without celery

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, ffmpeg, django-rest-framework

I have this code to transcode video and it works well without celery. With celery, the path of the file in the database shows a different path and the video cannot be played in the browser, but it saves the file in the correct location in the pc.

If I don't use celery, then the file path in database is `media/videos/videos/<filename>.mp4` and file also gets saved here. This way the template is able to play the video. But if I use celery, the output gets saved in `media/videos/videos/<filename>.mp4` but the path in database will be `media/<filename>.mp4` somehow and thus template can't play the video.

Is it because my page gets updated before the task? and not getting saved properly?

views.py

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form = VideoPostForm(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        video = form.save(commit=False)
        video.user = self.request.user
        video.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        # task_video_encoding(video.id)
        task_video_encoding.delay(video.id)
        return redirect('videos:my_video_home')
    else:
        raise ValidationError('Check all form fields.')
```

encoding.py

```
def encode_video(video_id):
    video = VideoPost.objects.get(id = video_id)
    input_file_path = video.temp_file.path
    # print(input_file_path)
    input_file_name = video.title
    #get the filename (without extension)
    filename = os.path.basename(input_file_path)
    # print(filename)
    # path to the new file, change it according to where you want to put it
    output_file_name = os.path.join('{}.mp4'.format(filename))
    # print(output_file_name)
    # output_file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, output_file_name)
    output_file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'videos', 'videos', output_file_name)
    # print(output_file_path)

    for i in range(1):
        subprocess.call([settings.VIDEO_ENCODING_FFMPEG_PATH, '-i', input_file_path, '-codec:v', 'libx264', '-crf', '-preset',
                    '-b:v', '3000k', '-maxrate', '-bufsize', '6000k', '-vf', 'scale=-2:720',
                    '-codec:a', 'aac', '128k', '-strict', '-2', output_file_path])
    # Save the new file in the database
    video.file = output_file_name
    video.save(update_fields=['file'])
    print(video.file)
    video.temp_file.delete()
```

models

```
class VideoPost(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title               = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    temp_file           = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/temp_videos/', validators=[validate_file_extension], null=True)
    file                = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/videos/', validators=[validate_file_extension], blank=True, max_length=255)
    post_date           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Posted")
    updated             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Updated")
    slug                = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
```

Can anyone help me how to change this code in a way to show the converted video properly in the template.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug by using `print(video.file)` to see if the output is `<filename>.mp4` or `videos/videos/<filename>.mp4`. I am skeptical that it will only printout the file name and not the url path, which is what you need.

Some suggestions:

1. In your `template`:
   Change `{{ video.file }}` to `{{ video.file.url }}`. See what it prints out.
2. Your current `output_file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, output_file_name)` will be something like `media/<filename>.mp4`. The one you commented out will give output `media/videos/videos/<filename>.mp4`. I am not sure what your `subprocess`function would do with `output_file_path`, but you can see if it has any problems in there.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I tried printing it out and it shows only '<filename>.mp4'  and not the full path. How can I change that?

Comment: There is another thing which I found out now. If I don't use celery, then the file gets saved in media/<filename>.mp4  and not in media/videos/videos/<filename>.mp4. This way the template is able to play the video. But if i use celery, the output gets saved in media/videos/videos/<filename>.mp4 but template can't play it since the path in database routes to media/<filename>.mp4 .

Comment: Hello @Danny, I just updated my answer with suggestions. Did you try the first suggestion with changing changing {{ video.file }} to {{ video.file.url }} in your template?

Comment: Yep..when I changed it to file.url then its not playing the video and if no videos are there, it shows an error.

The rest I somehow managed to make it work, but I have updated the question with the new problem. This problem exists only when I use celery now  to transcode the video. else it works fine.